# The domain of a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]

I'm assuming the green underline should say $t \geq 0$

I have shown that $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$  $\forall t>0$, however I am struggling to show it's the case $\forall x$ st $x \in[0,L]$.

If I aim to prove by contradiction and let there be a value $r \in [0,L]$ st

$u(r,t)\neq X(r)T(t)$ how would I proceed?

Even if it were the case that:

$u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ $\forall t \geq 0$ and $\forall x$ st $x \in[0,L]$

would this imply what is underlined in green (with $t \geq 0$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDE is usually meant to be satisfied on the open set $t > 0$, so the green underline is correct as is (and anyway, at $t = 0$, we are imposing a condition on the function itself, not its partial derivatives).

Writing $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$ is an *ansatz*; that is, we are just *guessing* that the solution can be written in this form, and then tracking the resulting implications:

"**if** $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$ **then** $T''/c^2T = X''X$ for all (appropriate) $t,x$ and if $T''/c^2T = X''X$ for all (appropriate) $t,x$, **then** $T''/c^2T = \lambda = X''/X$"

The reason that this guess is justified is usually covered at some point later in time; indeed, you probably do **not** have the tools at the moment to prove that all the solutions are of this form.

Comment: But why are the appropriate values $t>0$ and $\forall x \in[0,L]$?